# CSS doesn't work on Masterpage as well as the Content Pages of that masterpage in design mode in VS 2017?

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, master-pages

I've two master pages in my asp.net project, both are using same style sheets. On one master page and its respective content pages, the CSS works perfectly in design mode. But on the other master page and all its Content Pages design page turns blank.

When I remove the CSS link on that masterpage then Design mode works fine. I am new to this please help.

**Note:
both CSS works fine when running the project, the problem is just in design mode.**

Comment: Check the path to your css file.

Comment: i'm using same path with another CSS but it works fine, CSS files are located in the same folder

Comment: I think its path issue. Open page source and check for stylesheet path. (click on the css link in page source. If it's 404 then path issue otherwise syntax error)

Comment: @Znaneswer  this is what the link to the css i'm using  [link] <link href="~/dist/css/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />

Comment: and in page source while clicking on css its open the file without any error e.g (404)

Comment: Try in incognito(private window) or another browser it might be browser cache issue. If path mentioned correctly it would definitely applies to the page.

Comment: @ Znaneswar dude you didn't get my question i've said there is no issue with the working of CSS when starting the proj in VS, but my problem is it can't show the "design mode" of master please check my question again.Thanks

Comment: Please add some reference code etc. so we might see what is happening  - you say one is and one is not working, put both up so we can compare.